# Inserting HTML and PHP into PHP variable

Tags: php

I am trying to insert HTML and PHP into a PHP variable, but a syntax error is thrown:

```
    $nestedData[] = $row["titulo_anuncio"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["texto_anuncio"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["fecha_anuncio"];
    $nestedData[] = <<<EOD
<div>
<a id="<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
            <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
            </a>
</div>
EOD;
```

The error is thrown at the last $nestedData[] variable.

Comment: You're already in PHP. Read the heredoc page on the PHP manual for how to output variables. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc (in particular, the bit titled "Example #2 Heredoc string quoting example")

Comment: that should have thrown you a parse error

Comment: thank yoy @ceejayoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$nestedData[] = $row["titulo_anuncio"];
$nestedData[] = $row["texto_anuncio"];
$nestedData[] = $row["fecha_anuncio"];
$nestedData[] = <<<EOD
<div>
<a id="{$row['emp_id']}" class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">
        <img src="edit.png" width="20px" />
        </a>
```

EOD;

You can't echo `$row['emp_id']` within a line defining a string.